# Delete row with php

Tags: php, mysql

i currently have a SQL Database where i store some data.
That data is getting viewed on a website with the following code:

```
 echo "<tr><td>" . $row["project"]. " " . "</td><td>" . "  ". $row[ "project_desc"]. " " . "</td><td>" . "  ".  $row["hours"]. "</td><td>" . "  ".  $day. "</td></tr>";
```

But now i want it to have a extra tab where you can delete the row that is showed on the website from the database.
How can i do that?
if you need it, i use MySQL
And im using mysqli

Comment: Are you already using mysqli or PDO to insert into the database?

Comment: Add your Extra Tab too to the code so that it will be useful for getting better results

Comment: @Nordy Vlasman. I have provided you with clear explanation about what you needed and made my suggestions too. Have a look and share thoughts. If you face any hindrance let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this code inside your row-

```
<td><a href="delete.php?id=<?echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
```

when user clicks "Delete" then delete.php is called, so purchase id which want to be deleted should be transfer via delete.php,

**delete.php**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
mysql_query("DELETE from purchase WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: If i do this i get a empty page

Comment: you need to create `delete.php` file

Comment: you have to create a delete.php page and you have to connect with the database and after that you have to run this operation- $result = mysql_query("DELETE from purchase WHERE id='$id'"); if($result){ redirect('');}

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used along with `prepared statements`.

Hence i am suggesting you to learn the PDO tutorial from this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) and this is very useful for developing in the future projects.

To delete a single row in a table, you use the DELETE statement with a WHERE clause that specifies which row to delete.

Example for the MySQL Delete: http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/7.html

**Delete Example using mysql:**

1. In the list page where you display the data you need to add up the code for sending it to the `delete.php` page or you can delete it in the same page where you list the data.
2. Below i will provide you with two methods of how to pass the data.

> **Method One:** Same page delete

```
<td><a href="?id=<?echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
```

> **Method Two:** Delete.php page delete

```
<td><a href="delete.php?id=<?echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
```

> PHP code to delete the data from the table:

If you need to delete the data from the list page itself or you are going to delete in the `delete.php` page you need to follow up the same code to get the `REQUEST` from the URL.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
{
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$query="DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE `id`='".$id."'";
$execute = mysql_query($query);
echo "Data Delete Successfully";
}
?>
```

If you are going to delete in the `delete.php` page you need to connect the **database.php** file into that page.

**delete.php**

```
<?php
include('database.php');
//Followed by Delete Code over Here.
// And then you have to redirect the page using the header location
header('Location: BACK TO YOUR LIST PAGE');
?>
```

Hope so my explanation will be clear for your understanding purpose and you can get it make working on the next projects on the fly.

**Delete Example using PDO:**

```
<?php

/**
 * PHP MySQL Delete Data Demo
 */
class DeleteDataDemo {

    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_NAME = 'classicmodels';
    const DB_USER = 'root';
    const DB_PASSWORD = '';

    /**
     * PDO instance
     * @var PDO 
     */
    private $pdo = null;

    /**
     * Open a database connection to MySQL
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // open database connection
        $conStr = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s", self::DB_HOST, self::DB_NAME);
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO($conStr, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete a task based on a specified task id
     * @param int $id
     * @return bool true on success or false on failure
     */
    public function delete($id) {

        $sql = 'DELETE FROM tasks
                WHERE task_id = :task_id';

        $q = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        return $q->execute([':task_id' => $id]);
    }

    /**
     * close the database connection
     */
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->pdo = null;
    }

}

$obj = new DeleteDataDemo();
// delete id 2
$obj->delete(2);
```

Here i have found a very good tutorial for learning purpose please learn using this [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-delete/).